# Visualize QUrl in debug as string in VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, debugging

Generally, I like QUrls, but its such a pain to debug code with a lot of QUrls in code, and I cant see the actual url string in debug, I have to put some debug calls to toString in code. Is there any possibility to make it visible in debug watch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is old, but I've just stumbled upon this problem myself and decided to solve it somehow. The solution is crude, to say the least, but it works.

The problem with QUrl is that is uses pimpl for all of its internals and you don't have access to the definition of `QUrlPrivate` while debugging. The solution here might break once anything in QUrl is changed, as it is based on offsets of `QUrlPrivate` members. So if anything breaks in future versions, you could adjust offsets and you're good. This is as of Qt 5.3.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">

    <Type Name="QUrl">
        <DisplayString Condition="reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d) + 8)->d->size">{*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d) + 8)}://{*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d) + 20)}{*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d) + 24)}</DisplayString>
        <DisplayString>{*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d) + 24)}</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[scheme]">*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d) + 8)</Item>
            <Item Name="[host]">*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d) + 20)</Item>
            <Item Name="[path]">*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d) + 24)</Item>
            <Item Name="[query]">*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d) + 28)</Item>
        </Expand>
    </Type>


</AutoVisualizer>
```

Just save it into (for instance):

`%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Visualizers\QUrl.natvis`

Hope it's useful to someone.

**EDIT:**

This assumes you have natvis for other Qt types installed, especially `QString`.

Comment: Jeez, why isn't that already contained in the Qt Vs Tools. You just saved my day.

Comment: path for VS2015: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the QT VS add-in adds pretty print support for VS 2012.
Get it from [here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/07/03/visual-studio-add-in-1-2-2-released/)

You can add your own pretty print on your [see how QT does it](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/vstools/source/803678eef900077c5047afc2ab2999f7bf08f6db%3atools/Qt4EEAddin/qt5.natvis).

The natvis files add this functionlity.

** Edit **
The natvis file shipped with Qt's VS Addin only declares QUrl but doesn't add the required natvis code for printing it. Interested users can modify this file to add QUrl viewing functionality.

Comment: QT VS add-in adds pretty print support dont work for QUrls, it still seen in debug not as strings. And in natvis file it looks like 
`<DisplayString Condition="d.type == QMetaType::QUrl">Url</DisplayString>` What I supposed to change?

Comment: That's too bad. Within `Qt5.natvis` there's a declaration for it but no internals on how to display the URL string. See [here](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-labs-vstools/blob/master/tools/Qt4EEAddin/qt5.natvis)

Comment: You can see other examples within the natvis file. Other natvis files ship with VS (e.g. for STL and MFC), they can also be used as  references.

Answer (score 0):

There is update of @W.B. [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25482845/16605194) for 64 bit version Visual Studio 2017 and Qt 5.12.9. Only offsets were changed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">

    <Type Name="QUrl">
        <DisplayString Condition="reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)
+ 4+4)->d->size">{*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)
+ 4+4)}://{*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)
+ 4*2+8*3)}{*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)
+ 4*2+8*4)}</DisplayString>
        <DisplayString>{*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)
+ 4*2+8*4)}</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[scheme]">*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)
+ 4+4)</Item>
            <Item Name="[host]">*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)
+ 4*2+8*3)</Item>
            <Item Name="[path]">*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)
+ 4*2+8*4)</Item>
            <Item Name="[query]">*reinterpret_cast&lt;QString*&gt;(reinterpret_cast&lt;char*&gt;(d)
+ 4*2+8*5)</Item>
        </Expand>
    </Type>


</AutoVisualizer>
```